# How do I identify specific entity within a FlxGroup from FlxG.collide?

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

How do I make it so that when a bullet from the bullet group collides with an enemy from the enemy group, only the two hitting eachother will get affected?

I tried doing (In playstate):

```
if (FlxG.collide(bullet, enemy)){
        bullet.kill();
        enemy.kill();
    }
```

But the only thing this succeeded in doing is killing the entire group. How do I only kill the ones affected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Haxeflixel API docs](http://api.haxeflixel.com/flixel/FlxG.html#collide):

```
collide(?ObjectOrGroup1:FlxBasic, ?ObjectOrGroup2:FlxBasic, ?NotifyCallback:Dynamic‑>Dynamic‑>Void):Bool
```

so I think you can use something like:

```
FlxG.collide(
    groupBullets, 
    groupEnemies, 
    function (bullet:FlxObject, enemy:FlxObject):Void {
        enemy.kill();
        bullet.kill();
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to pass in a notification callback:

https://github.com/HaxeFlixel/flixel/blob/24529ac96d4ad49a5f0c7e64799d0197cee9049e/flixel/FlxG.hx#L395

So something like this is what you want:

```
FlxG.collide(bulletGroup, enemyGroup, collideBulletEnemy));

function collideBulletEnemy(bullet:FlxObject, enemy:FlxObject):Void
{
    bullet.kill();
    enemy.kill();
}
```

Some more explanation:

The collide() function in flixel lets you pass in either an object or a group to either parameter, and tells you if those two things collide. In the case of two objects, you can directly follow that test up with logic operating on those two objects. But if one of the objects is a group, you don't know based on the test alone which things collided, so you need to rely on a callback you supply yourself to get that specific information.